# Answering my own question

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I have asked some questions that nobody can answer; sometimes I find a solution, which is a workaround and is working fine for me, though it is not a real answer. In most cases the problem is a missing feature in a module. 
Should I share my progress as an answer, and leave the answer unaccepted so others can find a better solution?

I normally don't care about things like reputation, but in this project it seems important not to have a low acceptance rate. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the missing feature is caused by a bug in the module, then you should report a bug report in the project queue on Drupal.org.
If you created code for a feature that is not implemented in any module, then posting that as answer would help any future users who have your same problem, and need to resolve it.

I would avoid reporting a solution that requires to change the content of a module file, whatever the module is a Drupal core module, or a third-party module.
I would also avoid writing as answer something that is not really an answer: An answer should answer the question being asked. If, for example, the question was about how to do something with a module, and the answer is something similar to "I decided to use another module," then the answer is not really answering the question, and as such can be flagged as, "not an answer."

Answer (score 2):

Instead, file those questions as issues on drupal.org.

But, if you must, accepting your own answers doesn't affect reputation and is acceptable.